# Is there a recursive way of making this array of strings?

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm currently learning C++ and have written a bit of code that selects and plays a random film quote.

The starting point of the code is an array of strings that looks like this:

```
string filmQuotes[] = { "film1.wav", "film2.wav", "film3.wav" etc etc "film40.wav" };
```

As all the strings have the pattern film+n.wav I thought there must be a better way of declaring them?

Something like:

```
int i;
for( i = 1; i < 41; i++ ){
    filmQuotes[] = "film"+i+".wav";
}
```

I know the above is a bit of mixture of languages but hopefully you'll understand what I'm looking to do.

Thanks

Comment: You can use *iteration* to fill a `std::vector`. Also please read about [`std::to_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best way would be to use `std::vector` instead of C-style array:

```
std::vector<std::string> filmQuotes;
filmQuotes.reserve(40); //only needed to avoid a couple reallocations, can be ommitted
for( i = 1; i < 41; i++ ){
    std::string name = "film" + std::to_string(i) + ".wav";
    filmQuotes.push_back(name);
}
```

Could be done a little bit fancier with [`std::generate_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate) from `<algorithm>` (lambda captures are available from C++14 and up):

```
std::vector<std::string> filmQuotes;
std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(filmQuotes), 
                40, 
                [fileNumber=1]() mutable { return "film" + std::to_string(fileNumber++) + ".wav"; });
```

Or without lambda captures:

```
std::vector<std::string> filmQuotes;
std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(filmQuotes), 40, [](){ 
     static int fileNumber = 1;
     return "film" + std::to_string(fileNumber++) + ".wav"; 
});
```

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot What is wrong with static?  It's scoped to the lambda which can't be accessed after the expression so there is no reuse concerns.  It also saves from having a weird looking capture and having to specify the lambda as mutable.

Comment: @NathanOliver There are both versions now :)

Comment: @Yksisarvinen a big thank you for your comprehensive answer. I've marked it as the answer to the question as it seems to cover different ways to achieve the same thing. I've just got to dissect it now and try and understand it better! Thanks again for taking the time and trouble to answer my question so well. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way to do it is as follows:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> filmQuotes;
    for (int i = 0; i < 41; i++)
        filmQuotes.push_back("film" + std::to_string(i) + ".wav");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for recursion here, a loop will serve you well.  Using a `std::vector` if the size is only known at run time, or a `std::array` if the size is known at compile time you can loop through the indices and convert it to a string using [`std::to_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string)  This gives you a `std::string` object that you can add your string literals too.  That would give you code like

```
std::size_t size = some_value;
std::vector filmQuotes;
filmQuotes.reserve(size);
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    filmQuotes.emplace_back("film" + std::to_string(i) + ".wav");
```

or

```
constexpr std::size_t size = some_constant_value;
std::array<std::string, size> filmQuotes;
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    filmQuotes[i] = "film" + std::to_string(i) + ".wav");
```